# Convert image to base64 and send to graphQl in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, base64

How can I convert an image selected from imagepicker into base64 before sending it to graphql?

I set useState varaibles to set

```
const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
```

What can i do here to convert?

```
   const choosePhotoFromLibrary = async() => {
    const permissionResult = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();

    if (permissionResult.granted === false) {
      alert("Permission to access camera roll is required!");
      return;
    }

    const pickerResult = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync();

    if(!pickerResult.cancelled) {
        setImage(pickerResuls.uri);
    }
```

then I grab the image from and set it to the useState varaible

```
 <View style={styles.picContainer}>
     <AddPicButton
      onPress= {choosePhotoFromLibrary}
      image= {image}
      />
      <Text style={styles.bottomText}>ADD A PICTURE</Text>

 </View>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out ImagePicker has its own base64 conversion

```
const pickImage = async () => {
        // No permissions request is necessary for launching the image library
        let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
            mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
            allowsEditing: true,
            aspect: [4, 3],
            quality: 0,
            base64: true
        });

        console.log(result);

        if (!result.cancelled) {
            setImage(result.uri);
        }
        console.log(result);
        
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageEditor.cropImage(imageUrl, imageSize, (imageURI) => {
      ImageStore.getBase64ForTag(imageURI, (base64Data) => {
          // base64Data contains the base64string of the image
      }, (reason) => console.error(reason));
 }, (reason) => console.error(reason));
```

Comment: Will this replace all the image picker code or will this be under and i set the image uri to the const PickerResult

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).